# The stereo mix is always recorded

Tags: windows, audio, recording

Since I bought a new headset (Sennheiser PC360) I have noticed that even though I record from the headset microphone, system sounds leak through. At first I thought it was sound leaking out from the headphones into the microphone. But I have ruled this out since if I mute the microphone (on the headset) the system sounds are still recorded.

How is this even possible? I use the integrated sound card on the motherboard, and I have tried both the front panel mic and the back panel microphone input.

It is worth noticing that the stereo mix is recorded even if I disable the stereo mix in Windows recording settings. I seems to me very unlikely that this has anything to do with my new headset, but I can't figure out why this started to happen!? Is this a **Windows 7** bug?

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Many thanks in advance!

UPDATE: I have figured out that if I play e.g. music through my speakers instead of my headphones and simultaneuously mute my headset microphone I do not head any sound at all when I record from the headset mic.

This to me indicates that the problem might be either with the headset, or with the motherboard sound card?

Comment: There is a feature in Windows 7 for "sound isolation," but I don't remember where I've seen it. I encountered the same issue in Skype calls and Mumble chats, and managed to fix it by identifying that "sound isolation" option. Sorry I couldn't be of more help!

Comment: Thanks for your reply James! I cannot find anything related to this using google. However, I have made a discovery and I will update my original post!

Comment: Did you ever found a proper solution? I'm running in the same very problem. I have posted my question here with the details: http://superuser.com/questions/1151630/windows-audio-being-recorded-as-if-stereo-mix-was-enabled

Comment: Hi @MatteoMosca. I think that the motherboard is actually defect. Improper insulation or grounding or something similar. I will reply more thoroughly to your question.