# Windows audio being recorded as if "stereo mix" was enabled

Tags: windows-10, audio, audio-recording

My problem: windows sound (for instance, playing a youtbue video, or a videogame sound output) gets sent to the "recording channel", causing unwanted side effects, like:

- While playing online and using VOIP, my game audio is sent to teammates
- While recording my voice, any windows sound that plays is also recorded

This should happen only when "Stereo Mix" is enabled, but in my case it happens all the time.

To rule out some potential crap I did a fresh install of Windows 10 LTSB 2016 edition, but the problem did not go away.

I just installed motherboard chipset and audio drivers. The MOBO is an MSI GAMING 150A Pro.

The problem manifests when I use a headset with two jacks (audio and mic). If I plug in 2 different separate devices, for instance the audio plug of a headset and the mic plug of a different headset the problem does not manifest.

I have tried with 3 different headsets just to be sure not to have a defective one. The problem manifested with all 3 of them when both jacks of the same headset are used, and never manifested by mixing the jacks.

I also tried using both rear audio connectors on my MOBO and the front ones. Same results.

As of now I don't have the slightest idea what could possibly be wrong. Windows installation is fresh, tried multiple headsets.

Any clue would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I have a Sennheiser PC360 headset and my workaround it to plug in the mic in the back of the computer and the headphones in the front panel of the computer. I have also verified that there is no problems with my headset.

Furthermore, I have tried installing a Asus Xonar STX sound card and plugging in my headset into the new soundcard but the problems were only amplified with a lot of extra static noise. I tried the soundcard in my GFs computer and there were no problems there.

My only explanation left is either

1. That my motherboard is defect (I have an Asus motherboard)
2. I didn't ground the motherboard correctly when building the computer. Or damaged it in some other way.

I don't have any other issues with the motherboard.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, although it does not provide me with a solution, it's surely more useful insight. I've had mine assembled by professionals and I checked the work myself (I usually assemble my computers myself but this time I did not have the time) and the work has been done perfectly. It's probably defective. I've contacted MSI in regards of this problem and they answered with a firs tetnative "reinstall the drivers solution" which did not work. I replied, let's see what happens.